# Getting a maximum of 2 values of a column based on having same values in the first field using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, maxlength

[image]

I have three separate columns: `Link_Id`, `NEW`, `Length` in a data frame.

I want to group similar `Link_Id`s together and then collect their `Length` values, out of those having the maximum `Length` value I want to return their (`Link_Id`) and (`NEW`) column values.

```
import pandas as pd
# List all columns you want to include in the dataframe. I include all with:
cols = ['LINK_ID', 'NEW', 'Length']  # Or list them manually: ['kommunnamn', 'kkod', ... ]
# A generator to yield one row at a time
datagen = ([f[col] for col in cols] for f in vlayer.getFeatures())
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=datagen, columns=cols)

dff = df.groupby((df['LINK_ID'].shift() != df['LINK_ID']).cumsum())

for k, v in dff:
    print(f'[group {k}]')
    print(v)

result = df.groupby('LINK_ID').agg({'Length': ['max']})
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your data. You can provide a sample of your dataframe as a table or by posting the output of `df.head().to_dict()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
result = df.loc[df.groupby("LINK_ID")["Length"].idxmax()]
```

Comment: any ideas on how to apply a for loop and get print of the values to know whether this worked or not? @not_speshal and how do I retrive other column values.